# Not exactly the right answer

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, wrong-answers

Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19607266/2024761).

Now this question has few answers. One of the answers from a person seems to be pretty much what the OP wants and I went ahead and upvoted it. But there is another answer for that question which doesn't quite fit the bill. [This is that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19607301/2024761). If you have a look at it, it actually suggests the OP to change the constraint and try that answer, which the OP clearly declined as its not feasible. And somebody felt that it was a good answer, so they upvoted it also. Also, the poster of the answer doesn't want to take down his answer(that's his wish and I've no problem with that).

My question is, what do I do in such a situation? Do I just downvote that answer and move on?! Because I really feel that the answer under discussion is not right answer and the OP of that answer, despite acknowledging it and saying that he would delete the answer, clearly hasn't done so. I can't blame the answerer that he's doing that for just reputation. But I can't let it be as such either. I'm really in a fix. What do I do in such a situation? Please advice.

Note: The comments section of that answer will be a bit helpful too, in this case.

Comment: That's what the voting system is there for.

Comment: Okay, I guess everybody feels that I just downvote and move on. I thought in case we knew that it was a wrong answer, we could do something about it. Nevertheless, that's the piece of advice I wanted from the Community. This closes the Q/A here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In any case, such answers can be helpful.  Sure, it wasn't the right answer for the OP, but then, the OP is *not* the person we're keeping the answers online for — their problem has already been solved, and if nobody else cared, we might as well just delete the whole question as soon as an answer was accepted.

The real point of SO, however, is *not* answering specific questions — that's just a means to an end.  The real goal is to compile a large collection of useful answers, so that others who have the same or a similar problem can find them later.

Sure, the specific suggestion to change the placeholder syntax from `? foo ?` to `{1} foo {2}` was declined by the OP.  But it's still a good suggestion, and who knows, it just might be *exactly* the right answer for the *next* person to come across that question and its answers.

In any case, even when a question explicitly states a specific (but seemingly arbitrary) constraint, in my experience it's often a good idea to suggest answers that require relaxing that constraint, at least if doing so will result in a significantly better solution.  Sure, there *might* be a good reason for the constraint, but it's also possible that the OP has fallen into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) trap, and only thinks that they must solve the problem in a particular way, when in fact there are other, better ways.

Answer (score 11):

It is an attempt at answering the question. That makes it a *valid* answer. It's not as if the post is trying to sell you a product, is asking another question, or just plain nonsense.

You may *disagree* with the approach, and you can express that disagreement by downvoting the answer, or discussing the approach with the author in comments. But *that's it*.

The post doesn't need any discussion here or attention from a moderator, really.

Comment: I edited the question title for this very reason. I realized it after posting the question, hence edited it later. But then, when the poster acknowledges that it is not the right answer, even in that case, nothing need be done?

Comment: No, why? Just vote.

Comment: @R.J Downvote it and move on to the next question.

Comment: @R.J: Nope. That's what voting is for, to vote up answers you feel deserve to be noticed, downvote what you feel is not helpful. Pick whatever criteria you like to vote on, but voting is what it is about here.

Comment: There's a distinction between "answering the question" and "solving the problem the question is about". Given the number of XY problems posted daily, I'd say the latter are much more valuable to the community.